# Online Document Editing in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, document

My requirement is that i want to implement something similar to Google Docs in my website.

I want the user to be able to open word, pdf documents from my website without using MS office and pdf reader and  they should be able to edit and save those documents in the server.

What should I do? Are there any third party tools for that?

Comment: I don't know of any such tool, but good luck with that.

Comment: PDF cannot be edited. Also, i dont think that there is client side tool for web page that can open and edit word files. You have to parse it on server, but that is also very difficult. Only option is FCKEditor, TinyMCE or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want components that are like Google Docs.  Unless you're google, you'll have to do a lot of work to get from the currently available components to Google Docs.  If components were on par with Google Docs then component vendors would be offering cloud based Office apps too, right?

[FckEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)  Opensource.

[ASP.NET libraries that work with PDF and MS Office formats.](http://www.aspose.com/categories/default.aspx) Commercial

[Telerik RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx) I use this one for the spell check.  Commercial, source available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the below third party :  
1. http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/dotnetwpf/overview/
2. http://www.aceoffix.com/overview.html 
3. https://www.devexpress.com/ 
4. http://www.aspose.com/total-component-suite.aspx